# Haskell: Typeclass implies other typeclass

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to have a typeclass imply another typeclass in Haskell? For example let's say there is a bunch of "things" that can be ordered by an "attribute":

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int }

Person p1 <= Person p1 = (age p1) <= (age p2)
```

To avoid repetition one could define a "orderable by key" type class

```
class OrdByKey o where
  orderKey :: (Ord r) => o -> r
  x <= y = (orderKey x) <= (orderKey y)
```

Then the instance declaration for `Person` could look like this

```
instance OrdByKey Person where
  orderKey Person p = age p
```

Now this does obviously not work for multiple reasons. I wonder if it's possible at all?

Comment: If your goal is just to order based on a specific field in your record, you could always just define the instance of `Ord` for `Person` to compare that particular field.

Comment: @sabauma yeah but I'm looking for a generalization of that "can be compared by some key" thing.

Comment: For this particular example, take a look at the [comparing](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) function: `comparing age you me`

Comment: For a more general operator then `comparing` you could take a look at [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v:on). It has type `(b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`, so `comparing age = on compare age` but you could also make `on (==) f` to test two things for equality after applying `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have specified it, the `OrdByKey` class can only have one instance
per type, when it sounds like you would like to be able to declare an instance
for each field in your record type.

To accomplish that, you will have to put the field type into the class
definition as well. This lets you do something like the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int }

class (Ord r) => OrdByKey o r where
   orderKey :: o -> r

instance OrdByKey Person Int where
  orderKey p = age p

x <=? y = (orderKey x :: Int) <= (orderKey y :: Int)
```

However, you can only have one instance per field type, so if your
`Person` type looks like

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int, ssn :: String}
```

you will not be able to have a version to compare on both the `name` and
the `ssn` fields. You could get around this by wrapping each field in a
`newtype` so each field has a unique type. So your `Person` type would look
like

```
data Person = Person { name :: Name, age :: Age, ssn :: SSN}
```

That would lead to a lot of `newtypes` floating around though.

The real downside of this is the need to specify the return type for the
`orderKey` function. I would recommend using the `on` function from
`Data.Function` to write the appropriate comparison functions. I think a
function like

```
compareByKey :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Bool
compareByKey = on (<=)
```

generalizes your idea of "can be compared by some key". You just have to give
it the function that extracts that key, which would be exactly the accessor
functions for your `Person` type, in this case.

I can't think of an instance where the `OrdByKey` class would be useful and trying to overload the `<=` with multiple versions for the same type seems like it would be down right
confusing in practice.

Comment: Looks like using multi-param type classes is the clean way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
instance Ord Person where
    compare p1 p2 = compare (age p1) (age p2)
```

Now the standard `<=` operator will work on `Person`s and compare their ages.